# Keycloak 20.0.1 not logging out after calling logout endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have a Spring boot application using Keycloak as authorization server. when a protected url is opened in browser, the user gets redirected to login page provided by Keycloak. After successful login the user is redirected to the requested url. On this page I have a link pointing to the logout endpoint of Keycloak. The link is like this:

```
https://keycloak-server/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout?client_id=my-client&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/web/home
```

After clicking on this link, user is redirected to a page provided by Keycloak asking if they really want to logout. After confirming the logout, user is instantly redirected to the url provided in `post_logout_redirect_uri`. However if the user navigates to the protected page, they are still logged in.

I don't see any error logs in Keycloak server logs. I have also set the `Valid post logout redirect URIs` in Keycloak admin panel.

I have also tried to set the `id_token_hint` instead of `client_id` but that also didn't solve the problem.
anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that my approach will only end the session on the keycloak side. I had to log out the client too. I did this by adding a `logoutSuccessHandler`:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain webSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.authorizeRequests(
            auth -> {
              auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
            })
        .logout()
        .logoutUrl("/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .and()
        .oauth2Login()
        .build();
  }
```

```
private OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
    OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler successHandler =
        new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
    successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:8081/web/home");

    return successHandler;
  }
```